# PG Terminate Backend

Tags: php, database, postgresql, freeze

Is there any problem using this query for some functions, when the function that has called this query will also run.

```
SELECT pg_terminate_backend(pid)
FROM pg_stat_activity
WHERE pid <> pg_backend_pid()
  AND datname = 'database'
```

Answer (score 0):

The condition `pid <> pg_backend_pid()` makes sure that the statement will not terminate the database session that is running the statement, so there is no problem with that.

There could of course be all kinds of problems when you terminate database connections. For one, each of these sessions will receive an error, and the work that the sessions did in the current transaction will be rolled back.

You have the [freeze](/questions/tagged/freeze) tag on this question: if you cancel anti-wraparound autovacuum runs like this, you can get into all kinds of trouble eventually.